# How to calculate the peak power on a specific point on pulse-train given in volts?

Tags: voltage, power, oscilloscope

So, I have gathered with my osciloscope a pulse-train in volts. So, the height (y-axis) is 5 volt. I know the current (in mA) for the circuit I measure, and I want to have an estimation of the peak power on the given pulse-train, on a specific point on the peak of the pulse. How can I find it? I don't what to calculate the energy or the power on all the pulse-train. I just pick a random point on the pulse-train and I want to know what is the power on this specific point. In other words, I want to translate the volt/DIV I see to my osciloscope to power/DIV if that is possible. Any ideas?

Comment: Volts times amps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instantaneous power is simply voltage multiplied with current, i.e.

\$p(t) = u(t) \cdot i(t)\$

If the load impedance is real (or resistive) than you simply square and scale the voltage, i.e.

\$p(t) = u^2(t)/R = i^2(t) \cdot R\$

If the load is complex than things get a lot more complicated. If we can get both waveforms on the scope and if the scope can multiply them you can directly look at the power wave form and get the peak. Otherwise you will probably have to capture both waveforms and multiple them offline.